# MySQL: Select Data from Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 order tables

`Orders1`:

```
OrderNumber, TransactionID, TrackingNumber
```

`Orders2`:

```
OrderNumber, TransactionID, TrackingNumber
```

`Orders3`:

```
OrderNumber, TransactionID, TrackingNumber
```

I'm displaying the total number of orders that are not complete so I need to select from the tables where the `TrackingNumber = ''`

Comment: you can use mysql joins

Comment: How exactly are these tables related? Is it possible to a same OrderNumber identify both an Orders1 and an Orders2 row, for example?

Comment: They don't have anything in common bar the structure. We have orders coming in from 3 different sources and are stored in different places. One is eBay another is Amazon for example. The Order Numbers are unique to the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM orders1 WHERE TrackingNumber = ''
UNION
SELECT * FROM orders2 WHERE TrackingNumber = ''
UNION
SELECT * FROM orders3 WHERE TrackingNumber = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using subqueries.

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders1 WHERE TrackingNumber='')
  + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders2 WHERE TrackingNumber='')
  + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders3 WHERE TrackingNumber='')
AS `total`
FROM DUAL;
```

Tell me if it works as expected :)

It is worth saying that you should index `TrackingNumber` fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
    sum(a.subtotal )
from
    (select count(*) as subtotal from Orders1 where TrackingNumber=''
    union all
    select count(*) as subtotal from Orders2 where TrackingNumber=''
    union all
    select count(*) as subtotal from Orders3 where TrackingNumber=''
   ) a
```